# How do I get deck.gl and react-map-gl to display correctly?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, deck.gl, react-map-gl

[Here is a code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/deck-gl-and-mui-react-e3t23?file=/src/App.js) where I am trying to display a map inside of a specific component. But, I am not able to get the deck.gl and react-map-gl divs to live inside their parent. instead, they spill out to the extent of the document body.

The basic layout of the example is:

```
        <Box id='mapcontainer'>
            <DeckGL id="deck-gl">
                <MapView id="map"  >
                    <StaticMap/>
                </MapView>
            </DeckGL>
        </Box>
```

It appears that Deck.gl is creating a `<div>` and a `<canvas>` element between the `<Box id='mapcontainer'>` div and the `<DeckGL id='deck-gl'>` div, and I can not get the div and canvas to live inside of their parent Box.

The `id` of the `<div>` and the `<canvas>` appear to be created from the id passed into the DeckGL component, `id="deck-gl-wrapper"` and `id="deck-gl"` respectively. Where `"deck-gl"` is the `id` I passed into the `<deckGL>` component.

That may or may not be the actual problem, but using the elements inspector in devtools that is my best guess right now.

[image: element structure screenshot from devtools]

Can anyone help me figure out why deck.gl and react-map-gl components are not living within their parent bounds? Even when I set the `parent` and/or `canvas` props in the `DeckGL` component?

Documentation links:
[react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs)
[deck.gl](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/deck)

A functioning example is included in the codesandbox linked above. I have included many of the things I have tried as comments but no luck so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/deck-gl-and-mui-react-e3t23?file=/src/App.js

Thank you...

For local quick reference, the app.js file looks something like this.

```
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import DeckGL from "@deck.gl/react";
import { MapView } from "@deck.gl/core";
import { LineLayer } from "@deck.gl/layers";
import { StaticMap } from "react-map-gl";

const MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = <tokenInCodeSandboxIfYouNeedIt>

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
    longitude: -122.41669,
    latitude: 37.7853,
    zoom: 13,
    pitch: 0,
    bearing: 0
};

const data = [
    {
        sourcePosition: [-122.41669, 37.7853],
        targetPosition: [-122.41669, 37.781]
    }
];

function App() {
    return (
        <Box
            id='mapcontainer'
            sx={{
                border: 1,
                height: 450,
                width: "auto",
                m: 5
            }}
        >
            <DeckGL
                initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
                controller={true}
                id="deck-gl"
            >
                <LineLayer id="line-layer" data={data} />
                <MapView
                    id="map"
                    controller={false}
                >
                    <StaticMap
                        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
                        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} 
                    />
                </MapView>
            </DeckGL>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow the deck.gl component to take up the available space of the parent component you can add `position: 'relative'` into the overrides for your Box with an id of mapcontainer.